# My node modules deployed to Azure despite .gitignore

Tags: node.js, git, azure, azure-web-app-service, gitignore

So I pushed my code to an Azure website and had this `.gitignore` file in place, but it still pushed all of my `node_modules` folder contents to the site:

```
# dependencies
/node_modules

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Not sure why it did this. Used the `create-react-app` to start this project and did an initial push with my local git to Azure.

Why did this happen?

Can I simply delete all the content within the appservice and re-push? If so, isn't there I need to delete or reset to ensure this new push goes right?

Thanks much.

UPDATE:

Here is my file structure with regards to the node modules:

[image]

Comment: Well, `/node_modules` points to the root of the mount point, (you know, where `/etc`, `/root`, `/usr` are), so use relative paths instead, for example `node_modules`.

Comment: You can amend your commit. Check out `git amend` command

Comment: So then you are saying it should be `./node_modules`?